# EMF resource load - SAXParser reading map twice

Tags: resources, saxparser, emf

I'm having problems with persistence in EMF. The problem occurs when I add an element to a file that contains a map of elements. The process is:

```
Load file
Add element
Save file
```

The first time I add an element, it works fine. But if I try to add another, it reads
the list in twice before adding the new element. All subsequent uses also read the list twice.

**EXAMPLE**

I start with a file that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<org.eclipse.mbt.core:CoreServicesResources xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:org.eclipse.mbt.core="http://org/eclipse/mbt/core">
  <primaryResources>
    <elementsMap key="1">
      <value URI="1">
        <traceabilityProperties traceable="true" derived="true" topLevel="true" />
        <keywords tags="foo" />
      </value>
    </elementsMap>
  </primaryResources>
</org.eclipse.mbt.core:CoreServicesResources>
```

If I add a new element, I end up with a file that looks like this, which is correct:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<org.eclipse.mbt.core:CoreServicesResources xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:org.eclipse.mbt.core="http://org/eclipse/mbt/core">
  <primaryResources>
    <elementsMap key="1">
      <value URI="1">
        <traceabilityProperties traceable="true" derived="true" topLevel="true"/>
        <keywords tags="foo"/>
      </value>
    </elementsMap>
    <elementsMap key="2">
      <value URI="2">
        <traceabilityProperties traceable="true" derived="true" topLevel="true"/>
        <keywords tags="bar"/>
      </value>
    </elementsMap>
  </primaryResources>
</org.eclipse.mbt.core:CoreServicesResources>
```

However, if I then add another element, I get this, which is incorrect:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<org.eclipse.mbt.core:CoreServicesResources xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:org.eclipse.mbt.core="http://org/eclipse/mbt/core">
  <primaryResources>
    <elementsMap key="1">
      <value URI="1">
        <traceabilityProperties traceable="true" derived="true" topLevel="true"/>
        <keywords tags="foo"/>
      </value>
    </elementsMap>
    <elementsMap key="2">
      <value URI="2">
        <traceabilityProperties traceable="true" derived="true" topLevel="true"/>
        <keywords tags="bar"/>
      </value>
    </elementsMap>
    <elementsMap key="1">
      <value URI="1">
        <traceabilityProperties traceable="true" derived="true" topLevel="true"/>
        <keywords tags="bar"/>
      </value>
    </elementsMap>
    <elementsMap key="2">
      <value URI="2">
        <traceabilityProperties traceable="true" derived="true" topLevel="true"/>
        <keywords tags="foo"/>
      </value>
    </elementsMap>
    <elementsMap key="3">
      <value URI="3">
        <traceabilityProperties traceable="true" derived="true" topLevel="true"/>
        <keywords tags="bar"/>
      </value>
    </elementsMap>
  </primaryResources>
</org.eclipse.mbt.core:CoreServicesResources>
```

When I debug the code, the problem seems to be happening somewhere in the parser. I'm using the Java SE-11 System library, and the parser is `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl`

Has anyone else had problems like this?

Comment: I don't understand how reading the list twice would lead to adding more elements that what you are trying to do? Did you place a breakpoint around EList.add or the getter of your feature? And how are you doing the add to the list?

Comment: I don't understand it either. I debugged right down into the SAXParser class, looked at the buffer in the inputstream and it was fine, it matched the file it was reading. But then it passed the contents of the buffer to the parser, and the XML came out with each element duplicated. I add new elements to the map like this: `coreServicesResources.getPrimaryResources().getElementsMap().put(elementIdentifier.toString(), element);`

Comment: After adding the putting the element, does the model look alright? My guess is your metamodel is setup weirdly because your elementsMap has several elements with the same key which should be impossible. Do you have access to the metamodel/edit code?

Comment: The elementsMap is of type EcoreEmap, which is basically just a list - I'm not sure that it polices the keys like a true map class - so I do end up with several elements with the same key. As far as the metamodel/Edit Code is concerned, I haven't generated that, I only generated the Model Code. How will it help me to generate the Edit Code?

Comment: EcoreEMap implements EMap so it's supposed to be an EList of Map$Entry with unique keys so it's really strange that you would have this behavior. Is it possible your call to put() is in some multithreaded stuff ? In that case you'd probably want to use EMF.edit and the EMF Transactions to make sure everything is alright.
You did not answer whether your model looks alright after the put operation and before serialization

Comment: Thanks - I'll look at the EMF.edit. If I put a breakpoint after the put operation, the model looks like the file - in other words, multiple copies of elements that have the same key.

Comment: You need to show a relevant part of your meta model to get help.

Comment: Thanks Petur - I ended up solving it with the help of some people on the Eclipse forum.